# single copy of member variable in singleton class

Tags: java, singleton

I was trying to practice Singleton Class here.

```
public class StaticClass {

    public static StaticClass staticObject = new StaticClass();

    private int counter;

    private StaticClass() {

    }

    public static StaticClass getMyObject() {
        return staticObject;
    }

    public Integer showCounter() {  
        return ++counter;
    }
}

public class TestSingleton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new TestSingleton().testImplementation();
    }

    public void testImplementation() {
        StaticClass obj1 = StaticClass.getMyObject();

        Integer obj1Int = obj1.showCounter();

        StaticClass obj2 = StaticClass.getMyObject();

        Integer obj2Int = obj2.showCounter();

        StaticClass obj3 = StaticClass.getMyObject();

        Integer obj3Int = obj3.showCounter();

        System.out.println(obj1Int+","+obj2Int+","+obj3Int);
    }
}
```

But I am little confused to maintain single copy of counter variable here.

After running the program, I am getting different values of counter as `1,2,3`.

Any suggestions as why there are multiple values of ?

Comment: showCounter() changes the value of counter by incrementing it before returning the value. So the output you're seeing is expected.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting different numbers every time you call it because your `showCounter()` method has a side effect of increasing the counter when you call it.

```
public Integer showCounter() {  
    return ++counter;
           ^^----------- This adds 1 to the counter.
}
```

It's more than a bit confusing to have a side effect like that on a method called `show`. I would break it up into two methods:

```
public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

public int incrementCounter() {
    return ++counter;
}
```

Also, take a look at `AtomicInteger` in the JDK. It does all this for you if all you need is a counter that's threadsafe and atomic.

Comment: Thanks @Todd,(just for curosity) is it possible to maintain single copy of counter even after incrementing it since we have single copy of class ?

Comment: Yes, there is only one copy of the counter. It's static, so that means there is only ever one of them not matter how many instances of the class you create.

Comment: is it possible to get output as `3,3,3`?

Comment: Not if your `showCounter()` method keeps increasing the counter.

Answer (score 1):

That is how a singleton works.

If you compare `obj1 == obj2` you'll see that it returns true.

So when you call showCounter on either object, the same counter, on the only instance of `StaticClass`, gets updated.